# Migration Issue: New Site won't open -- server doesn't see file that is there

Tags: installation

I am migrating a Drupal site from my localhost to the most current Bitnami Drupal AMI on Amazon:

- I uploaded the DB successfully.
- I moved the files correctly.
- I copied over the modules and libraries.

I got the WSOD, changed the error reporting and now, upon opening the site I get:

```
    Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 
'/opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/views/includes/view.inc' 
(include_path='.:/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php') in 
/opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 3066
```

But the file is in the proper spot, within the structure outlined by Bitnami:

```
/home/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/views/includes
```

How do I convince drupal (or php) to use `"/home"` instead of `"/opt"?`  I suppose I could just try a symlink but... that seems like such a kludge.  I'd like to do it the "right" way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe a simple symlink is all it takes.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are all under /home instead of /opt you could just setup a virtualhost and point to the /home docroot

e.g, for apache, where www.example.com is your site domain name:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.example.com
     DocumentRoot /home/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs
     CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example-access.log combined
     ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/example-error.log          

     php_value memory_limit 256M
     php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
     php_value post_max_size 128M      
     php_value max_execution_time "360"

     FileETag ALL

     <Directory /home/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs>
         RewriteEngine on                
         RewriteBase /                   

         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

         Options -Indexes
         AllowOverride All

         # Follow symbolic links in this directory.
         Options +FollowSymLinks                   

         # Customized error messages.
         ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

         # Set the default handler.
         DirectoryIndex index.php  

         php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
         php_value register_globals                0
         php_value session.auto_start              0
         php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
         php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
         php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0   

         # Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
         <IfModule mod_expires.c>             
             # Enable expirations.            
             ExpiresActive On                 
             # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
             ExpiresDefault A1209600                        
             # Do not cache dynamically generated pages.    
             ExpiresByType text/html A1                     
         </IfModule>                                        
         <IfModule mod_deflate.c>                           
         # Use mod_deflate to compress text content as required and supported by the client
         # Note that the frontend will automatically gzip content if supported using PHP functionality
         AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript    
         </IfModule>                                                                                  

     </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Redirect non-www to www version of site
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Add to **/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf**

Then, to enable:

```
sudo a2ensite example.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```